# What is wrong with this vb wfa code?

Tags: vb.net, checkbox

What is wrong with this code for multiple checkboxes in vb wfa, it says it can't be converted to a boolean:

```
If ch1.Checked & ch2.Checked = True Then
        score = score + 1
End If
```

Comment: @KenWhite No it´s not. The And Operator in VB .NET is `And`  not `&`

Comment: & is the string concatenation operator.  It doesn't care much for `If "FalseTrue" Then`.  Nobody does, that's truetrue.  Use And or AndAlso.  And do favor Option Strict On for a while so the compiler can tell about typos like this.

Answer (score 2):

In vb, the operator is **And**:

```
If (ch1.Checked And ch2.Checked) Then
    score = score + 1
End If
```

Comment: how can i have 2 radio buttons in 1 program with out one overwriting the outer

Answer (score 2):

If you want compare that both checkboxes are checked then `AndAlso` will be little bid better, because it will not evaluate second checkbox value if first is `false`

```
If ch1.Checked AndAlso ch2.Checked Then
    score = score + 1
End If
```

In c# it is same as `&&` operator